Lstlisting border gaps
Im trying to highlight a line of code in a a lstlisting with a frame. However, when i render it, there is a tiny gap in the frame
    \documentclass{report}
\usepackage{graphicx} % Required for inserting images
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}     % for éô
\usepackage[english]{babel}     % for proper word breaking at line ends

\usepackage{listings}           % for control of 'itemize' spacing
\usepackage{todonotes}          % for clear TODO notes
\usepackage{hyperref}           % page numbers and '\ref's become clickable

\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{diagbox}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}
        \centering
    \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.45\textwidth}
    \centering
    \begin{lstlisting}[numbers=left ,frame=tlrb, showlines=true,escapechar=\%]
    mov.w r0, sp
    mov.w r2, #4
    mov.w r8, r8
    %\colorbox{lightgray}{mov.w r8, r5}% 
    mov.w r8, r8
    mov.w r8, r8
    bx lr
    \end{lstlisting}
    \caption{Cycle count:  16}
    \label{fig:str_chain2}
    \end{subfigure}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}


Anyone have any idea how to fix this? (edit: added full code)

Welcome to TeX.SE! Your given code does not result in the shown image. Please make your code snippet be compilable, then we do not have to guess, what you are doing ...

The \colorbox increases the line spacing, so there will be breaks in the frame. If you use the \hl command from the soul package, this unpleasant phenomenon will not occur. Another advantage of the \hl command is that there is no horizontal text shift.
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{listings,xcolor,soul}

\newcommand\myhl[1]{{\sethlcolor{lightgray}\hl{#1}}}

\lstset{
 basicstyle=\ttfamily,
 columns=fullflexible,
 numbers=left,
 frame=tlrb,
 escapechar=\%
 }

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}
mov.w r0, sp
mov.w r2, #4
mov.w r8, r8
%\myhl{mov.w r8, r5}% 
mov.w r8, r8
mov.w r8, r8
bx lr
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}



A quick 'n dirty solution would be to ignore the additional height of the colored line (using \smash) and letting LaTeX know the height of the uncolored line without displaying it (using \vphantom):
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}
  \begin{figure}
    \centering
      \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.45\textwidth}
      \centering
      \begin{lstlisting[numbers=left,frame=tlrb,showlines=true,escapechar=\%]
        mov.w r0, sp
        mov.w r2, #4
        mov.w r8, r8
        %\smash{\colorbox{lightgray}{mov.w r8, r5}}\vphantom{mow.w r8, r5}% 
        mov.w r8, r8
        mov.w r8, r8
        bx lr
      \end{lstlisting}
      \caption{Cycle count: 16}
      \label{fig:str_chain2}
    \end{subfigure}
  \end{figure}
\end{document}

It would be a good idea to write your own macro for that, put this in your preamble:
\newcommand\hightlight[1]{%
  \smash{\colorbox{lightgray}{#1}}\vphantom{#1}
}

You can then call it using \highlight{mow.w r8, r5}.


Any idea what causes the minor offset to the right? So far the best solution btw so much appreciated!!!
